# Glassware Starter Project(Java) works fine on localhost, but not in app engine

Tags: google-mirror-api

I have build it from eclipse and ran on development server, it works, when I deploy it on app engine from eclipse, I got this following error, any idea why?

Very first time it went up to oauth2 dance, but it did not succeed, I have fixed redirect-url on api console, then, localhost worked, I did deployed again onto app engine, but it did not work, I got this error:

```
Error: 500 Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.
```

Error log in App engine console:

```
2013-06-07 01:59:36.619 /oauth2callback?code={removed now} 500 2416ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
68.5.238.205 - - [07/Jun/2013:01:59:36 -0700] "GET /oauth2callback?code={removed now} HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36" "{my appid }.appspot.com" ms=2416 cpu_ms=1581 cpm_usd=0.000087 app_engine_release=1.8.0 instance=00c61b117c2c977fac245e8480eff747e75eb6
I 2013-06-07 01:59:34.228
com.google.glassware.AuthFilter doFilter: Skipping auth check during auth flow
I 2013-06-07 01:59:34.230
com.google.glassware.AuthServlet doGet: Got a code. Attempting to exchange for access token.
I 2013-06-07 01:59:35.427
com.google.glassware.AuthServlet doGet: Code exchange worked. User 115370471277937689999 logged in.
W 2013-06-07 01:59:36.614
Error for /oauth2callback
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
    at com.google.glassware.NewUserBootstrapper.bootstrapNewUser(NewUserBootstrapper.java:54)
    at com.google.glassware.AuthServlet.doGet(AuthServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in App Engine and the Google OAuth endpoints. It's being tracked in the [Glass issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=99). You can star that issue to receive updates as the investigation proceeds.

In the mean time, check out the [.NET](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-dotnet) and [PHP](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-php) quick starts. They're working great.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate your feedback.